# change part of link with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have datatable rows links coming with data and I wanna change part of the link text.

So, for example, when it's `200.0.0.10` change it to `160.11.10.12`

I tried it with this code but nothing happened, the link remains unchanged:

```
var url = (data['Chemin'])

window.location.href = url.replace("http:\\200.0.0.10", "\\160.11.10.12\Images");
```

Comment: Are you sure than `data['Chemin']` value is `http:\\200.0.0.10`?

Comment: If you are just wanting to replace them... why are you trying to redirect your whole page to it in the same go?

Comment: yes in my data['Chemin'] value is http:\\200.0.0.108............and i wanna just change http:\\200.0.0.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `//` in your url and it should work.

```
 window.location.href = url.replace("http:\\200.0.0.10", "http://160.11.10.12/Images");
```

If that doesn't work it's because of the escaped backslashes so do:

```
 window.location.href = url.replace("http:\\\\200.0.0.10", "http://160.11.10.12/Images");
```

Using backslashes `\` in JS is an escape character which means that the next character has special meaning e.g. `\n` means new-line. So if you want  a `\` in a string you have to double it.